# libgdx animation callback?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

How do I check if current animation is completed so that I can follow up with another set of animation? For example, I am playing player hurt animation and I want to play some bloods splashing animation (different spritesheet) once the player hurt animation is finished.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `OnActionCompleted` listener to your `Action` with Action's method:

```
 /** 
  * Sets the listener to be invoked when the action is finished.
  * @param listener
  * @return this 
  */
 public Action setCompletionListener (final OnActionCompleted listener)
```

Eventually you can use:

```
public boolean isDone()
```

to check if Action execution has finished.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I am new to Android and libGdx. Sorry if my question sounds too silly for you. :)

I am testing my code on the sample project `Super Jumper` where I have my `Player` object that holds all the player attributes like velocity, position and etc. I am using the **WorldRenderer* pattern to draw the sprites on screen. 

Can I add the `setCompletionListener` on the `Player` class which is not extend from `Actor`?